# Getting parental status from a self-referencing table

Tags: mysql, self-reference

Let's say you have the following table:
items(item_id, item_parent)
... and it is a self-referencing table as item_parent refers to item_id.

What MySQL supported SQL query would you use to SELECT each item in the table along with a boolean value that indicates whether that item is a parent / has other items referencing to it?

If you have the following data in the table:

```
item_id     item_parent
----------- -----------
1           0          
2           0            
3           2          
4           2          
5           3
```

... the query should be able to retrieve the following set of objects:

{"item_id":1,"is_parent":0}
{"item_id":2,"is_parent":1}
{"item_id":3,"is_parent":1}
{"item_id":4,"is_parent":0}
{"item_id":5,"is_parent":0}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  i.item_id,
        item_id IN
        (
        SELECT  item_parent
        FROM    items
        )
FROM    items i
```

Comment: I like the SQL, but it won't show the items that don't have parents, will it?  It looks like Emanuil wanted to get all the items back from the querry with the second column being a boolean showing it's parental status.

Comment: @AlCrowley: and yes, it will show all items, not only those with children. The `IN` predicate is in the `SELECT` clause, not `WHERE`.

Answer (score 2):

This returns all items and an integer specifying how many children each has:

```
SELECT T1.item_id, COUNT(T2.item_parent) AS is_parent
FROM items AS T1
LEFT JOIN items AS T2
ON T1.item_id = T2.item_parent
GROUP BY item_id
```

If you want a boolean (0 or 1) just change it to:

```
SELECT T1.item_id, COUNT(T2.item_parent) > 0 AS is_parent
FROM items AS T1
LEFT JOIN items AS T2
ON T1.item_id = T2.item_parent
GROUP BY item_id
```

Comment: Brilliant! A query that gets children count is event better. SQL is so powerful.

Comment: Yes, it was a wild guess that you might want to get the count rather than just a boolean, which is why I suggested this method. I got lucky! ;-)

Comment: If you only want the boolean, go with Quassnois solution, but if you want the child count too, go with this.

Comment: I'm lucky to have such a great answer. Thanks again!